# A lab activity for the Y-Combinator

Tags: labs, lambda-expressions

We are about to study the y-combinator as a culmination of lambda calculus, and I would like a shortish lab activity that is related to this idea.  We are currently working in Scheme, though I don't consider that to be important at this stage.  What I want (and what I lack) is something interesting that students can *do* with the concept of a lambda expression that takes itself and then acts recursively.

Comment: An example that seems to work is here: http://www.viksit.com/tags/clojure/practical-applications-y-combinator-clojure/

Comment: Does this help: RosettaCode Y-Combinator [Scheme](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Scheme) ? If so I can make it an answer.

Comment: @GuyCoder It certainly helps.

Comment: @Buffy The memoization example there is amazing. I'm still trying to make sense of it.

Answer (score 4):

One site that I find helpful for basic examples of coding task written in a multitude of programming languages is [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code). While it is not always a win when going there, I still keep it high on the list of sites to check when looking for teaching examples or code that demonstrates something.

In this case the combination of the programming language [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)), an example simple enough to use in a classroom and the [Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) [Y-combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) are satisfied by this example:

> Define the stateless Y combinator and use it to compute factorials and
>   Fibonacci numbers from other stateless functions or lambda
>   expressions.

```
(define Y
  (lambda (h)
    ((lambda (x) (x x))
     (lambda (g)
       (h (lambda args (apply (g g) args)))))))
 
;; head-recursive factorial
(define fac
  (Y
    (lambda (f)
      (lambda (x)
        (if (< x 2)
            1
            (* x (f (- x 1))))))))
 
;; tail-recursive factorial
(define (fac2 n)
  (letrec ((tail-fac 
             (Y (lambda (f)
                  (lambda (n acc)
                    (if (zero? n)
                        acc
                        (f (- n 1) (* n acc))))))))
    (tail-fac n 1)))
 
(define fib
  (Y
    (lambda (f)
      (lambda (x)
        (if (< x 2)
            x
            (+ (f (- x 1)) (f (- x 2))))))))
 
(display (fac 6))
(newline)
 
(display (fib 6))
(newline)
```

output

```
720
8
```

Bonus answer:

When others want to learn more about Lambda Calculus the first reference I always give is ["An Introduction to Functional Programming Through lambda Calculus"](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/library/functional_programming/gjm.lambook88.pdf)

Note: While the link is nice if you really do use the book often then please [purchase](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486478831) the book.

Comment: Now that I've seen your writeup, are you saying that the lab activity is, itself, to create `fib` and `fac`?

Comment: Yes. The activity would be first to create the Y combinator, then to verify that it works one could write `fib` and/or `fac`. I also find that reading the book noted is a gentler way to learning what is going on and why. While I don't know your end goal with Lambda Calculus. If I were teaching a class on it I would keep one of the goals being to understand [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) which is the basis for a lot of functional languages and language research.